# Error pushing user id to firebase DB

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire2

Hello I want store date on my DB for each user, for that I wants create a node with UID of each user.

I have an authentication service with that method:

```html
 signupCommerce(email: string, password: string){
    return secondaryApp.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(firebaseUser) {
      console.log("User " + firebaseUser.uid + " created successfully!");
       
        return firebaseUser.uid;
    });
  }
```

And a DB service with this method:

```js
createCommercePath(category:string,id:string, commerce:string, banner:string, logo: string, latitude:number, longitude:number){
    this.db.database.ref().child(category).child(id).push({
      name: commerce,
      bannerUrl: banner,
      logoUrl: logo,
      lat: latitude,
      lng: longitude
    });
  }
```

In my component my form call this method:

```js
 createCommerce(){
let commerceId = this.authService.signupCommerce(this.email, this.password);
this.db.createCommercePath(this.category, commerceId, this.commerce, this.bannerUrl, this.logoUrl, this.lat,this.lng);
  }
```

I am getting this error:

```html
Argument of type 'Promise<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `signUpCommerce()`-function returns a `Promise<any>`.

```
let commerceId = this.authService.signupCommerce(this.email, this.password);
```

Therefore `commerceId` will be of type `Promise<any>`

You could change your `signUpCommerce` function to something like this:

```
signupCommerce(email: string, password: string){
    return secondaryApp.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }
```

And then use it like this in `createCommerce()`

```
createCommerce(){
    this.authService.signupCommerce(this.email, this.password)
    .then(firebaseUser => {
        let commerceId = firebaseUser.uid;
        this.db.createCommercePath(this.category, commerceId, this.commerce, this.bannerUrl, this.logoUrl, this.lat,this.lng);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, How can i get the uid of  the Auth service and push to the DB.

Comment: The child method require a string i can't pass a Promise

Comment: Thank you, that works, but i don't know what is the difference between.

Comment: You propably be best off by reading up about [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), in short _'The Promise object represents the eventual completion (or failure) of an asynchronous operation, and its resulting value.'_

Comment: Youre welcome by the way! Glad it worked out for you!

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As described in the error, your method return a value of `Promise<any>`. As I understand, you want to get the string that return from this promise.
So, one option that I suggest you to use is: (use `rxjs`, you need to npm install it if you dont have it in your project yet)

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';
import 'rxjs/Rx' ;
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

signupCommerce(email: string, password: string){
  return secondaryApp.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).first().toPromise();
}
```

the code above is for your service function.
and the code below for the component use:`enter code here`

```
createCommerce(){
  let commerceId = this.authService.signupCommerce(this.email, this.password).then( response => {
     this.db.createCommercePath(this.category, commerceId, this.commerce, this.bannerUrl, this.logoUrl, this.lat,this.lng);
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err); 

}
```

Enjoy :)